# Ill-formed program with a fixed enumeration instead of overflow

Tags: c++, enums, range, c++14

In the following declaration:

```
enum class en : signed char { A = 127, B };
```

*gcc* (and *clang*) says that the `B` value is outside the range of the enumeration, which is [-128, 127]. An error is also shown when writting:

```
enum class en : signed char { A = 128 };
```

However, in the second case, the initializer must be a converted constant expression from type `int` to type `signed char`, which disallows narrowing conversion and thus that construct is ill-formed.

But what about the first case? There's no initializer so that rule doesn't apply.

The standard says:

> **[dcl.enum]§2** An *enumerator-definition* without an *initializer* gives the *enumerator* the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous *enumerator* by one.

So, it's obvious that the choosen range (`signed char`) is not big enough to save the value `128`.

Maybe compilers decide to treat that case as a *rule violation* (and thus the program is ill-formed), but I don't see that as a rule violation, because it's not some kind of property of the program that violates a rule, but a command about what the compiler shall do. In this case, I would say it is a corner case not explicitely described or forbidden.

Comment: A corner case that has no explicitly or implicitly defined behavior is by definition undefined behavior.

Comment: Reading a bit further on [dcl.enum]§5: _" If
the underlying type is fixed, the type of each enumerator prior to the closing brace is the underlying type and the constant-expression in the enumerator-definition shall be a converted constant expression of the
underlying type."_ As the conversion (of 128 to `signed char`) is not possible you get the message.  source: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4687.pdf

Comment: I believe the sentence before your quote, *If the first
enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero.*, means that `B` is implicitly converted to `B = 128`

Comment: @RichardCritten The issue with `B` (int the first case, not the second), is that there's no `constant-expression`.

Comment: @NathanOliver ?

Comment: @Peregring-lk [dcl.enum]/2 states *An enumeratordefinition
with = gives the associated enumerator the value indicated by the constant-expression.*.  Then it says *If the first
enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero.*.  To me that means that `enum {a}` is transformed to `enum {a=0}`.  Taking in consideration the next sentence that you quote it leads be to beleive the `enum {a=127, b}` is transformed to `enum {a=127, b=128}` which is why you get the same error.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's not strictly the same, because "= previos + 1" or "= 128", are expressions, with types, and thus follows the rules and semantics of conversions and so on, according to their types. But that phrase says that it must assign the "next value", or in other words, the "bit pattern" that represents the "next value" according to that type, so it skips any rule related to expressions.